# Tomcat running error: Application not found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I created a simple Spring application, and run it using Tomcat 8.5.39.
It works nice in my PC but when I run it in my notebook, it open an error window: 
 [image]

It doesn't open browser window with error even, just start local server,
and open this error win after:

```
2019-04-05 05:41:04,084] Artifact SpringgMVC:war exploded: Artifact is 
deployed successfully
[2019-04-05 05:41:04,085] Artifact SpringgMVC:war exploded: Deploy took 
6 042 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slowed!!!
If you set up your tomcat like in any instruction, and see this message, it can be that you didn't set an browser in tomcat configuration
[image]

Click on browser icon and set your browser instead of default, it works for me.